# Bash Commands not working on Mac

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, macintosh, ruby

Hello I open my terminal window on Mac Os 10.6.8 as I am trying to update my ruby to 1.9.3 and the terminal gives me this response immediately as I open it:

```
-bash: export: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /usr/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /usr/sbin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/sbin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/usr/local/git/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /usr/X11/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /usr/X11R6/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/usr/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/usr/sbin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /sbin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /usr/local/git/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/usr/X11/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export: /Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin': not a valid identifier 
-bash: export:/usr/X11R6/bin': not a valid identifier
```

I tried to change my path but it did not work. I am not sure how to go about this problem and have been reading a whack load of forums. Any ideas?

Here is the bash_profile:

```
$ /bin/cat ~/.bash_profile

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.3
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/git/bin /usr/X11/bin /Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin /usr/X11R6/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/git/bin /usr/X11/bin /Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin /usr/X11R6/bin

##
# Your previous /Users/oskarniburski/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/oskarniburski/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-09-26_at_17:32:30
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-09-26_at_17:32:30: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Comment: You have an error in one of your bash initialization files. Please post the contents of `~/.bash_profile` and `.profile` if you are using the OSX terminal app and `~/.bashrc` if you are using another terminal.

Comment: Can you tell me how to access the contents of that file? Should I be using terminal?  am trying nano .bash_profile to access it but that is not working. I will post the contents afterwards! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just open a terminal and run this `cat ~/.bash_profile` and then `cat ~/.profile`. If one of the two files does not exist, don't worry, just post the one you have.

Comment: I really do appreciate the help, but                               $ cat ~/.bash_profile
-bash: cat: command not found                                         $ cat ~/.profile
-bash: cat: command not found

Comment: You're very welcome :). OK, your bash is all screwed up so it can't find it. OK, try this: `/bin/cat ~/.bash_profile` and `/bin/cat ~/.profile`.

Comment: I posted in the question description. Thanks again terdon!

Comment: The two lines under the RVM stuff are unquoted and breaking your shell..

Comment: I am trying to edit now using vi and nano, but both commands are still no recognized by bash! If you are correct, then I can change it just by quoting those two lines of code.

Comment: Use `/bin/cat` as I suggest in my answer or `/usr/bin/nano`.

Comment: I added quotations around the python parts, however it still unresponsive to bash commands like grep and other commands. I am seeming to spiralling in some destructive patterns

Comment: Rakso, come join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux), it will be easier to explain there. You will need to run `source ~/.bash_profile` or simply open a new terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the main issue here was that you had spaces separating directory entries in your `$PATH` and that you had these spaces in non quoted variables which confused `bash`.

What you wanted to do in this case was add a directory to your path. The correct syntax is `PATH="/foo:/bar/baz:$PATH`. Adding the `$PATH` to the end means that its current value will be appended to the end of the variable, that way you will not overwrite what was already there. The directories in `$PATH` are read in order so add it to the beginning if you want the new directories to be searched last: `PATH="$PATH:/foo:/bar"`.

Another problem was that you had many duplicate paths. You can find these by running

```
$ echo $PATH | perl -pne 's/:/\n/g' | sort | uniq -d
/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin
/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
```

Finally, you were exporting the `$PATH` multiple times which is pointless. I removed all duplicates and fixed your syntax and ended up with this:

```
# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.3
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}"

# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:$PATH"

##
# Your previous /Users/oskarniburski/.bash_profile file was backed up 
# as /Users/oskarniburski/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-09-26_at_17:32:30
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-09-26_at_17:32:30: adding an appropriate PATH 
# variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"

# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Copy that file, open your terminal and run these commands:

```
/bin/cp ~/.bash_profile ~/bash_profile.bad
/bin/cat > ~/.bash_profile
```

The first will make a backup of your current `~/.bash_profile` (just in case). The second will appear to do nothing but it will have opened `~/.bash_profile` for writing. Just paste what I gave above directly into the terminal then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. That should bring everything back to normal.

NOTE: You were specifying `/bin`,`/sbin`,`/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` in your `.bash_profile`. These are almost certainly already in your `$PATH` and don't need to be added. If they are missing (`echo $PATH` to see the current value) just add them using the syntax I described above.

Comment: Thank you so much terdon. You were a great help and I appreciate it so much. If there was a way I could pay you back I would, but I am very grateful!

Comment: @RaksoZrobin you're very welcome. If you want to pay me back, [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) this answer and come back and upvote it when you have the [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) :).